# Prove that this is a measure

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I have problems with this exercise

> Let $X$ be an uncountable set, and let $\Sigma \subseteq{}\mathcal{P}
>  (X) $ the $\sigma$-algebra.
>
> $    $$\boldsymbol{\beta} = \{A \subseteq{X} : A$ it is countable or
> $A^c$ it is countable $\}$
>
> Define $\mu: \boldsymbol{\beta} \to
>  \overline{\mathbb{R}_{+}} $ ($\mathbb{R}_{+} = [0, + \infty]$ ) as
>
> $\mu (A) = \left \{ \begin{matrix} 0 & \mbox{if }A\mbox{ is countable}
>  \\ 1 & \mbox{if }A^c\mbox{ is countable}\end{matrix}\right. $
>
> and prove that $\mu$ is a measure.

**My attempt:**

$\mu : C \rightarrow{\overline{\mathbb{R}}}$ is a measure if:

i) $\mu( \emptyset ) =0$

ii) If ${A_n}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq{C}$ such that $ \displaystyle\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}^{}{A_n } \in C$ and the $A_n$'s are disjoint

$$\mu(\displaystyle\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}^{}{A_n }) = \displaystyle\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}^{}\mu(A_n)$$

i) $\mu( \emptyset ) =0$ because the cardinality of  $\emptyset = 0$

ii) Let $\{A_n\mid n \in \Bbb N\}$ a collection of sets of  $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ disjoint two by two. Note that, since two by two are disjoint, there can be at most one with a countable complement. Then there are two possibilities: either they are all countable (and therefore their union is countable) or there is exactly one with a countable complement and the others are countable (and therefore the union has countable complement).

Thanks

Comment: I see no mistakes here. For future viewers of this page, you might make the title more specific, and replace $\Sigma$ with $\beta$.

Comment: Two by two is strange. The term pairwise is more commonly used to describe that concept.

Comment: You might want to give more detail on why sets with countable complement can’t be disjoint and why those two cases satisfy the formula.

Comment: Only I thought of this idea but how can I write it more formally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, as $X$ is uncountable, none of it's subsets are both countable and have countable complement. This fact makes $\mu$ well defined. To prove $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive, you can proceed using a proof by cases:

Consider a countable collection of disjoint sets $\mathcal{A}\subset\Sigma$. If all the sets in $\mathcal{A}$ are countable then you are done as a countable collection of countable sets is countable ([proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Countable_Union_of_Countable_Sets_is_Countable)), in particular: $$\mu(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n)=0=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}0= \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mu(A_{n}).$$ Suppose then that there exists an $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $X\setminus A_m$ is countable. Thus we have that all the sets in $\{A_n\}_{n\ne m}$ are countable as $$\{A_n\}_{n\ne m}\subset\mathcal{P}(X\setminus A_m)$$
since $\mathcal{A}$ is a disjoint collection. Therefore we have $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mu(A_n)=\mu(A_m)+\sum_{n\ne m}\mu(A_n)=1+\sum_{n\ne m}0=1.$$ Also, $X\setminus\bigcup\mathcal{A}$ is countable as $$X\setminus \big[(\bigcup_{n\ne m} A_n) \cup A_m \big]\subset X\setminus A_m$$ giving $$\mu(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n)=1.$$

Comment: It's not true that every subset of an uncountable set is countable or cocountable. Maybe you just meant to say that no subset is both countable and cocountable?

Comment: Yes that was wrong of me Alex. You are correct, I just meant to emphasize that you can't have a subset of X which is both countable and co-countable in this case. I will make the correction.

Comment: And thank you for pointing that out!